# How to make a call via host header in Asp.Net-Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to make a call to a server, passing in the host header in asp.net core. What is the syntax I need to be able to specify a host?

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://" + server.IPAddress + "/");
    // add host header here - server.HostName
    var response = await client.GetAsync(server.File);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // handle
    }
}
```

I am using [System.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/) from nuget for the DNX support, but I'm not wedded to that as a solution.

I cannot connect straight via IP as there are multiple sites on that IP on IIS differentiated via host headers.

In .Net 4 I used:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://" + server.IPAddress + "/" + server.File) as HttpWebRequest; 
request.Host = server.HostName; 
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    // handle
}
```

<sub>(Try / Catches omitted from code)</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HttpClient.DefaultRequetHeaders Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders(v=vs.118).aspx):

```cs
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://" + server.IPAddress + "/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = server.HostName;
    var response = await client.GetAsync(server.File);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // handle
    }
}
```